An object moving close to $c$ falling into a black hole
Assume there is an object moving at $0.99999999999........c$ (upto like a thousand 9s) towards the center of a non-rotating black hole in a straight line
Since it can't escape once it falls in where will it's energy go?
If it is simply converted into the black holes mass in accordance to $$\delta E=\delta M c²$$
And $$\delta E=\gamma_v M_{object} c²$$
Making $$\delta M_{black hole}= \gamma_v M_{object}$$
So if I am correct as the speed of the object falling into the black hole goes to $c$ the change in mass should go to infinity right?

Black holes aren't magic. What happens to the total energy (kinetic + potential + rest mass-energy) in a closed two-body Newtonian system? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_orbital_energy

If, when the object is far away, its total energy is $E=\gamma m_o c^2$, then the mass of the black hole would increase by $E/c^2=\gamma m_o$ where $m_o$ is the rest mass of the object. Note again that $\gamma$ of the object is measured far away from the black hole. The gain in speed of the object due to the gravity of the black hole does not affect the result. Also note that the object will slow down near the black hole and stop at the horizon, because the speed of light there is zero. This slowing down also does not affect the result.

The object's energy will simply increase the mass of the black hole.

If it is only one single particle we have conservation of momentum, but if we have two particles falling in from opposite sides with opposite momentum the momentum will sum up to zero and the mass will be increased by the conserved energy E=-pt of the particles.

With:
$$ \eta \equiv \frac{c - v} c = 10^{-1000} $$
I think we have more than the energy of the BH increasing.
Note that:
$$ \gamma = \frac 1 {\sqrt{1-(1-\eta)^2}} \approx
\frac 1{\sqrt{2 \eta}} \approx 10^{500} $$
where the 2nd approximation ignores the square root of 2 factor.
If start with a electron mass particle:
$$ E = \gamma mc^2 = 0.511 \times 10^{494}\,{\rm MeV} = pc $$
so
$$p \approx 10^{470}\,{\rm kg\cdot \frac m s} $$
impacting TON 618:
$$ M = 66\times 10^9\,M_{\odot} \approx 10^{41}\,{\rm kg}$$
basic kinematics says the worlds largest black hole will be accelerated to:
$$ \gamma' \approx \frac p M = 10^{459} $$
idk if that even works.
(Note: without the momentum, you have a Schwarzschild radius problem. I don't need to work it out, but ten to the 400 plus kg is going to be much larger than the visible universe).

I guess I was a little extreme with the numbers  (an unfortunate disaster has struck us as a black hole with a radius bigger than the observable universe has been created)

no, it hasn't! that's the point. You need to consider $E^2-p^2 = m^2$ for the radius in the rest frame. Which I think is related to the original question?

You are correct, but not for the reason you think. The mass of an object is a Lorentz scalar and therefore frame independent, meaning it does not change for different observers at different speeds. The formula
$$
E = mc^2
$$
is only valid in the rest frame of an object. For a general frame, this formula becomes
$$
 E_\text{total} = \sqrt{p^2c^2 +m^2c^4}
$$
Where the magnitude of the three-momentum $p$ can now be written as
$$
p = \gamma(v)mv
$$
And $v$ is the velocity of the object as measured in the frame. Note that this expression indeed diverges as $v\to c$, and therefore so does $E_\text{tot}$. In the rest frame of the black hole, a massive object approaching at speed $c$ would indeed instantly add an infinite amount of mass to the black hole (It should be clear that this is of course impossible). However, at no point do we give physical meaning to the quantity $\gamma(v)m$! The energy of the object then simply adds to the mass and curvature of the black hole. Where it really "goes" is an open question in physics.

The singularity is a moment of time the correct question when the objects goes when it hits the singularity.

@RootGroves according to classical GR, the singularity isn't anything. It's not part of the spacetime manifold, even though it can be understood as a limit point of all causal worldlines within the event horizon. Apart from that, I never mentioned the singularity. Our experimentally justified understanding of black holes ends at the event horizon. While the mathematical description of spacetime extends beyond this horizon, we cannot even in principle know if this description is in accordance with reality. Hence it is an open question what happens to matter that crosses the horizon.

I agree it is impossible to extract information of objects past the event horizon so it becomes like philosophy right?But the mathematics say that the singularity is a moment in time since space and time switch places past the EH of a black hole.

@RootGroves The Schwarzschild singularity is an infinitely long line that is spacelike along and lightlike across. So yes, it is a moment of time that happens everywhere in the (hyper)cylindrical space when it shrinks to the line of its axis. And if a single photon falls in, its spin would convert the black to rotating. Then the infinitely thin line of the singularity expands to become a very-very thin (hyper)cylinder of the Cauchy horizon (still spacelike along and lightlike across) with a strange word inside where time moves in loops and the ring singularity opens a door to other universes.

@RootGroves It makes no sense to speak of "moments in space" and "moments in time" seperately when dealing with relativity. There are only points in spacetime. According to the mathematical formulation of GR, you cannot find a single point on the spacetime manifold that corresponds to the singularity, so effectively  they do not exist in the physical world.

Inside the black hole the spacetime curvature is so extreme that space and time essentially become seperate entities.

@RootGroves No, that happens when spacetime is nearly flat and all observers move at speeds much smaller than $c$. Either way, it is true that the Schwarzschild metric contains no $dtdx$ cross-terms, but even in flat Minkowski space, time and space are inseperable. If you write the Schwarzschild metric in Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates, you will see that the radial and temporal directions have the same scale factor, all the way from infinity down to the limiting case of the singularity (where the scale factor is no longer defined).

@RootGroves “space and time essentially become seperate entities” - While normally this is incorrect, as already pointed out above, there is an advanced special case where this is actually true. As mentioned in the comment above, space and time are separate in the flat Galilean spacetime where the speed of light is infinitely larger than all other speeds. In the conceptual opposite case with a zero speed of light, space and time also can be separate. The details of this special case are described in several great answers here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3310040

@safesphere the keyword for this is "Carrollian physics", and there's recently been quite the fuss about its applications in CFT  and higher-spin theories of gravity. I am currently working on it as well as a side project!

@safesphere is hyped up by the back to back Superbowls....Mahomes carrying the Chiefs to victory ,regardless of that the dx determ close to singularity is 0 so time and space are essentially seperate.

@paulina Wow, it looks like my question 6 years ago has triggered interest and caused “a meteoric rise” in papers on the subject no one cared for since 1965 ;)


Anjan Sharma wrote: "Assume there is an object moving at 0.999... c
(upto like a thousand 9s) towards the center of a non-rotating black hole in a straight line. Since it can't escape once it falls in where will it's energy go?"

In that case we have an inelastic collision and the momentum will be transfered to the black hole itself, so you would get a moving black hole. Since the black hole's rest mass is probably much higher than the particle's rest mass the resulting speed will of course be slower.
If you have two particles falling in from opposite direction they will cancel each other's momentum and add their total energy which in free fall is a conserved quantity to the black hole's mass.
The total conserved energy is the sum of rest mass, kinetic and potential energy, so in a symmetric situation the total energy of a particle falling or escaping with the escape velocity is exactly its rest mass.

Anjan Sharma wrote: "So if I am correct as the speed of the object falling into the black hole goes to c the change in mass should go to infinity right?"

When crossing the event horizon all particles have the speed of light relative to the black hole's barycenter, but they still don't add infinite mass to the black hole.
The conserved energy of the particle is $\rm E=-p_t$ where $\rm p_t$ is the time component of the covariant four momentum.

“The total conserved energy is the sum of rest mass, kinetic and potential energy” - As mentioned time and again, there is no potential energy in GR. It doesn’t exist in reality, but is a made up concept to make Newtonian Gravity work. For example, if two equal rest masses $m$ fall to each other from rest at infinity, then in NG, the resulting mass is $2m$ on top of the energy of the collision; but in GR, the resulting mass is $2m$, including the energy of the collision. The difference is exactly the “potential energy” that is not there in GR and gives a wrong result in NG.

@safesphere Nonsense, the potential energy is defined as the difference between local and global energy, see A first course in general relativity, Figure 5.1:
"The gravitational potential energy must in some sense represent the difference between the sum of the energies of the particles and the total mass of the system." - we don't need Newton to calculate how much kinetic energy a particle can gain in free fall, that also works with Einstein, but the equations become slightly more complicated, I showed you that many times.

The total conserved Energy in Schwarzschild Droste coordinates is mc²√[(1-rs/r)/(1-v²/c²)], the kinetic mc²/√(1-v²/c²] and the potential energy the difference. The v is relative to the black hole in this coordinates, where in Gullstrand Painlevé it is relative to the free falling local observers, then the equation is slightly different, but the total energy E=-pt is the same in all coordinates. In my answers I usually choose the system of a far away and stationary observer, but it works in all coordinates.

When two objects with rest masses of $M$ and $m$ fall to each other from rest at infinity, the total momentum is zero and the total conserved energy is $(M+m)c^2$. Assuming no heat or any other radiation, the result of the collision is an object with the rest mass of $M+m$. This includes the internal heat energy generated by the collision of the objects. The same is true, if one (or both) of the objects is a black hole (assuming no gravitational waves or any other radiation), except in this case no heat energy is generated. Is this not true? Your total energy formula doesn’t match.

@safesphere Of course it matches, since v=c√(rs/r) the both brackets under the square cancel each other so the total energy of that particle is mc², so "my" total energy formula matches perfect and your argument does not contradict mine.

The textbook in your link overall is horrible with wrong statements. The Figure 5.1 is different from your description. It actually says, "Light is therefore redshifted as it climbs in a gravitational field", which is absolute false. The author compares the frequency measured in two different frames, which is absurd. Your quote actually is in 7.3: "The notion of gravitational potential energy, however, is itself not well defined in the new picture: it must [must it really?] in some sense [in which, Newtonian?] represent the difference..." Exactly my point. Stay away from this book.

"Potential energy" is a property of a force field. Gravity is not a force in GR, hence no potential energy. The mass of a weightless mirror box with photons is $m=E/c^2$ where $E$ is the energy of photons. Clearly this mass is frame dependent due to time dilation. Now replace mirrors with quarks and photons with gluons, whose energy constitutes 99% of baryonic mass, and you'd see that it's also frame dependent. In the Schwarzschild coordinates, mass is zero at the horizon and equals the rest mass at infinity. Hence the physical meaning of your "potential energy" is mass defect just like in QM.

@safesphere wrote: »Stay away from this book.« - I have 10 other books that say the same, but you already know that from the 100 discussions we already had about this. -  »Hence the physical meaning of your "potential energy" is mass defect just like in QM.« - I know, that's why I mentioned it since the question is about the mass, every argument you brought so far is just a confirmation of what I said, so I'm not sure if you're just trolling.

I am just pointing out that you keep referring to non-existing “potential energy” that is not even a concept in GR. This is misleading to those here who are more familiar with Newtonian Gravity than GR. Thinking of “potential energy” in GR kills the actual physical meaning of this theory. Getting rid of the made up and ugly concept of non-existing “potential energy” is the beauty and elegance of General Relativity - despite of tons of bad textbooks you have apparently collected :)

@safesphere I don't say this because I read it in a textbook but from my own experience since I use it in my own calculations, for example when I need to check how much kinetic energy is gained in free fall from one position to the other. The textbooks are just an argumentum ad dictionarium since you don't believe me.

Your math is correct. The only issue is the physical interpretation. No one feels a shame in using the mass defect in QM. The effect in GR is essentially the same. There is no need to refer to “potential energy” that doesn’t actually exist. It was invented, because Newtonian Gravity was a force field, but there is no need to confuse and unnecessarily complicate GR by grandfathering a non-existing and not applicable concept from the force field theory, which GR is not.
